# How to prevent clearing search text after select a result on search bar iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have a search bar and I'm searching locations using it. When I search and select a location, the search bar text is emptying. Is it possible to keep the selected text on search bar. Here what I tried,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SPGooglePlacesAutocompletePlace *place = [self placeAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [place resolveToPlacemark:^(CLPlacemark *placemark, NSString *addressString, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Could not map selected Place"
                                                        message:error.localizedDescription
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        } else if (placemark) {
            searchedString = place.name;
            [self.parent showHUD];
            [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];
            [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
            [self retrieveSearchResults:1 place:[place name]];
            [self.searchView setText:[place name]];
        }
    }];
}
```

How may I fix this?

Comment: Store the value in NSuserdefault and set the the textfield value with that.and whenever you first time run application  first time that time in view did load you can check NSobject of NSuserdefault is null or not.

Comment: I just tried `[self.searchView setText:@"Colombo"];` in `viewDidLoad` but it's not setting the text on search bar.

Comment: Have you set Datasource and delegate?

Comment: Yes. both `UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate`

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2857188/RecipeAppSearchBar.zip check this demo

Comment: there are two method     "- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
"          and       "-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString"     there is set string of search content

Comment: Nope. It's not working